# Query does not work with a parameter marker with preparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Excerpt from code

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =  connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sch.tab1 where col1 like lower ( 'ABZ' ) ");
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The above code executes successfully.

But when i try to execute this

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =  connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sch.tab1 where col1 like lower ( ? ) ");
preparedStatement.setString ( myValue );
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

It throws an exception."*STRING TO BE PREPARED CONTAINS INVALID USE OF PARAMETER MARKERS*"

What could be the problem here?

---

***Answer found, see the comments***

Comment: This is potentially jdbc-driver-dependent. What's your database?

Comment: Given the tags, I'd assume db2.

Comment: i found the answer. thanks to Paul Chernoch.
-- SELECT * FROM sch.tab1 where col1 like lower ( '' || ? ) --

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Carlos is on to something. Try

```
SELECT * FROM sch.tab1 where col1 like lower ( '' + ? )
```

or whatever passes for string concatenation operator in your version of SQL. Forcing a string context might get you past the error. May require extra parentheses.

Comment: ** '' + ?  ** , i never knew you can use + operator for string in SQL. atleast in DB2 you can not use.

Comment: Accepting as `SELECT * FROM sch.tab1 where col1 like lower ( '' || ? )` will work

Answer (score 4):

I *suspect* the problem is that you can't apply functions directly to parameters. Is there any particular reason why you want the lower casing to be performed at the database rather than in your code? (I can think of some potential reasons, admittedly.) Unless you really need to do this, I'd just change the SQL to:

```
SELECT * FROM sch.tab1 where col1 like ?
```

and call `toLower()` in Java, preferably specifying the appropriate locale in which to perform the lower-casing.

Comment: Currently i am doing 
"preparedStatement.setString ( 1,  myValue.toLower() ); "  
as  a work around, but why it is not possible to do by using markers?

Comment: I don't know - it could be a DB2 restriction, or possibly one in their JDBC driver. An alternative would be to create a stored proc which did the lower-casing for you...

Comment: maybe because the driver would not be able to determine the correct data type for the argument...

Answer (score 0):

For reference: I ran into the same problem while using the `NORMALIZE_STRING` function:

```
SELECT NORMALIZE_STRING(?, NFKD) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Error message:

```
THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF ARGUMENT 1 OF NORMALIZE_STRING IS INVALID. SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, DRIVER=4.13.111
```

Using the following statement solved the problem (`CONCAT`). Thanks to Paul Chernoch!

```
SELECT search_normalize(NORMALIZE_STRING(? CONCAT G'', NFKD)) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Note the "G" prefix for Unicode compatibility.